# Javassist seems to generate invalid field access code

Tags: java, javassist, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to augment some code with additional functionality during startup of my application. The whole setup itself is working fine, but there is one point where I think javassist might generate bad code.

I am doing this on a specific method on a specific class, I checked before that the return value is actually of type `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`.

```
ctMethod.insertAfter("$_.SOME_METHOD(); $_.SOME_FIELD = <...>;");
```

SOME_METHOD() and SOME_FIELD are both declared in `AbstractStringBuilder`, the superclass of `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`. Both are defined as public, `java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder` itself is only package-private.

The operation itself is successful, but execution of this code results in the error "`java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder from class <...>`". With print-debugging I found out, that accessing the method works fine but accessing the field crashes.

So I checked the generated bytecode:

```
...
invokevirtual #41 <java/lang/StringBuilder.SOME_METHOD>
...
getfield #72 <java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.SOME_FIELD>
...
```

So for accessing the method it resolves to `StringBuilder` itself, but for the field it resolves to AbstractStringBuilder which is not obviously not accessible from the location of the modified code. Btw, the decompiled bytecode looks just fine.

I am also accessing this field in my static code, so I checked the bytecode of this one:

```
...
getfield #37 <java/lang/StringBuilder.SOME_FIELD>
...
```

This is code compiled by default compiler and it does not use AbstractStringBuilder for reference.

So my question is: did I oversee something regarding the JVMs concepts of visibility and inheritance or does javassist not correctly resolves this?
I hope, my explanation is understandable - otherwise let me know and I will try to enhance it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in Javassist.

Fields are not virtual, by naming another class, you really access a different (shadowed) field which needs to be accessible by the class in question.

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer, I will raise an issue in the javassist project - or do you know whether there is one for this bug already?

Comment: Would not know of one.